# User authentication on multiple PC with the same username and password

Tags: windows

In our institute we would like to setup a system for the student. All the PC's are Win7 and we would like to achieve that the user don't have to sit always in the front of the same computer, but I it will be annoying to create user names on all PC. What server do we need(Windows 200x, Linux) to store the user data, and authentication parameters? How can we setup the PC?

Answer (score 1):

For centralized authentication and authorization, you need to set up some type of authentication domain. In Windows you would create an Active Directory domain. Once you've created the AD domain you would then join the computers to the domain.

Comment: A Samba domain would work as well. While AD does provide some nifty features it's not required for a simple scenario like this.

Comment: Is it possible to use an Ubuntu server?

Comment: Probably, but I can only speak to the Windows option available. As Ansgar stated in his comment, you can implement a Samba domain on Linux, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: I can vouch that it is possible to use a Samba server for this purpose, but it is not something that is easy to do and is nearly impossible for someone with limited experience in protocols like LDAP, Kerberos and SMB.  I would strongly reccomend a Windows server, especially if you can get Acedemic pricing.  You are looking at less than $200 for the server license.